# What are the steps required to solve this system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The system that I need to solve is
$$
\begin{align}
&i_1 + i_2+ i_3 &=0\\
&i_1+i_4+i_6 &=0\\
&i_5+i_6&=i_2\\
&-v_{s1} + i_1r_1 + i_3r_3 - i_4r_4 + v_{s4} &= 0\\
&-i_2r_2 + v_{s2} - i_5r_5 - i_3r_3 &= 0\\
&-v_{s4} + i_4r_4 + i_5r_5 - i_6r_6 - v_{s6} &= 0\
\end{align}
$$
for the variables $i_k$.

For the asker: the question as it should appear

[image]

You can see the original question at: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/ch2/node2.html :example 2. Please provide the steps. Thank U in advance.

Comment: What are the variables ? One way is to compute a Groebner basis (i suppose the system is quadratic, and not linear).

Comment: We have to find i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6.

Comment: This is a system of 6 linear equations in 6 unknowns. You can find methods in any linear algebra textbook, or online by searching for "system of linear equations".

Comment: Someone took the time to format your wretched question decently, and you rolled it back! Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: Then it is even linear, and you can solve it.

Comment: Sorry let me put it back.I did it because it did not make any sense to me.

Comment: What have you already tried?  What do you know about systems of simultaneous equations?  Also, please take the time to learn how to format your questions properly: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have not done this. It has been edited by Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, let's rewrite the system as
$$
\begin{align}
&i_1 &&+ i_2 &&+ \,\,\,\,i_3 &&&&&&&&=0\\
&i_1 &&&&&&+i_4&&&&+i_6 &&=0\\
&&&-i_2&&&&&&+i_5&&+i_6&&=0\\
&r_1i_1 &&&&+r_3i_3  &&-r_4i_4  &&&&&&= v_{s1}-v_{s4}\\
&&&-r_2i_2 &&- r_3i_3 &&&&-r_5i_5 &&&&= -v_{s2}\\
&&&&&&& +r_4i_4  &&+r_5i_5  &&-r_6i_6 &&= v_{s4}+v_{s6}\
\end{align}
$$
(the above should look like this):

$\hspace{14mm}$[image]

From there, you should be able to use Gaussian elimination

Comment: What have you written.I cannot understand

Comment: I just rewrote the system of equations so that the variables we want to solve for are lined vertically lined up.

Comment: The phrase, "multiplication-addition", means nothing to me, and I've been teaching Linear Algebra for 35 years.

Comment: @GerryMyerson after googling, I realize that not everyone uses the same term for it. That's the term I heard for Gaussian elimination before I was told it was Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Why has anybody given me 2 vote downs?

Comment: I think there might be a communication issue going on here. Can you look at my answer again? I've added something

Comment: So i can find the values of the six i variables by using the 1st three equation by using guassian elimination method, Right?

Comment: You can find the values by using all of the equations and using the Gaussian elimination method.  The trick for those last 3 equations is to put the constants (like vs4 and vs6) on the right side of the equation.

Comment: It does not appear as you have shown. It begins with "\begin{align}..."

Comment: All right.  Apparently, the computer you're using doesn't render mathjax.  To most other people looking at this question, what I wrote looks like the picture that I have uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Omnomnomnom. I finaaly understood.

Comment: Please put back the image.

Comment: I've changed the question so that, in the mean time, you can read it as I wrote it.  I put the image of your question up in your question.